# Facebook Open Graph URL with GET parameters not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an Open Graph Object page like this :

```
<html><head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# music: http://ogp.me/ns/music#">
        <title>OG Sample Object - Sample Song</title>
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="<?php echo FACEBOOK_APP_ID; ?>">
        <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo "MY SONG2"; ?>">
        <meta property="og:image" content="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png">
        <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo "{$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']}://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}"; ?>">
        <meta property="og:type" content="music.song">
</head>
```

I use Javascript to publish the action :

```
FB.api(
        'me/my_custom_app_dev:my_action',
        'post',
        {
            song: "http://" + location.hostname + "<?php echo SANDBOX_USER_PATH;?>" + "/component-details.php?type=song&id=1234",
            tags: tagList.valueOf(),  // tagged friend(s); if any
            message: messageText  // custom message; if any
        },
        function(response) {
            // handle the response
            if(response.id) {
                alert('Successfully posted on Facebook timeline.');
            } else {
                alert('Sorry, Failed to post on Facebook timeline.');
            }
        }
    );
```

The action is successfully posted on my timeline, but the post's URL on my facebook wall is missing parameters this part **?type=song&id=1234**

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the URL of **og:image** and after one or two tries it worked !
Maybe it was due to Facebook caching the URL.